# why is it considered bad to use short PHP tags?

Tags: php

I've always been told to use the long `<?php` tags instead of the short `<?` tags.
Is there some functional reason for this?

Comment: Don't listen to the hype/hate on this one. Use whatever tags you want if you are in full control of your server environment. The "conflicts with XML headers" argument is really moot if you are not working with XML. If you DO want to switch to "proper" tags later, doing a batch find/replace is not that difficult. I find that short tags save me lots of typing time while coding, look cleaner to my eye, and therefore are beneficial to my productivity.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php):

> PHP also allows for short open tags  (which are discouraged
>   because they are only available if enabled with short_open_tag php.ini
>   configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the
>   --enable-short-tags option.

That said, as long as you understand this I find the short tags great for HTML templates and such.